# Move all images in folder to subfolder, and update all references in text files to those images to their new location?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, grep

I have a folder which contains a ~50 text files (PHP) and hundreds of images. I would like to move all the images to a subfolder, and update the PHP files so any reference to those images point to the new subfolder.

I know I can move all the images quite easily (mv *.jpg /image, mv *.gif /image, etc...), but don't know how to go about updating all the text files - I assume a Regex has to be created to match all the images in a file, and then somehow the new directory has to be appended to the image file name? Is this best done with a shell script? Any help is appreciated (Server is Linux/CentOs5)

Thanks!

Comment: Use regex; `sed` is probably your best bet. And your PHP scripts should have a variable for the images directory, in case you need to change the location in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
for f in *.jpg *.png *.gif; do 
    mv $f gfx/
    for p in *.txt; do 
        sed -i bak s,`echo $f`,gfx/`echo $f`,g $p 
    done 
done
```

It finds all jpg/png/gif files and moves them to the "gfx" subfolder, then for each txt file (or whatever kind of file you want it edited in) it uses "sed" in-place to alter the path.

Btw. it will create backup files of the edited files with the extra extension of "bak". This can be avoided by omitting the "bak" part in the script.

Comment: Since there are hundreds of files, this will be very slow.

Comment: It could be done faster, but it is a solution. I would probably prefer to do it in Python instead and cache all the paths to change in a list and then apply those changes afterwards to the files in question.

Comment: This is what I ended up using - it was a little slow, but it did just the trick - Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`sed` with the `-i` switch is probably what you're looking for. `-i` tells `sed` to edit the file in-place.

Something like this should work:

```
find /my/php/location -name '*.php' | xargs sed -ie 's,/old/location/,/new/location/,g'
```

Comment: No need for `grep`: `find /my/php/location -name '*php'

Answer (score 0):

This will move all images to a subdir called 'images' and then change only links to image files by adding 'images/' just before the basename.

```
mkdir images
mv -f *.{jpg,gif,png,jpeg} images/
sed -i 's%[^/"'\'']\+\.\(gif\|jpg\|jpeg\|png\)%images/\0%g' *.php
```

If you have thousands of files, you may need to utilize find and xargs. So, a bit slower

```
find ./ -regex '.*\(gif\|jpg\|png\|jpeg\)' -exec mv {} /tmp \;
find ./ -name \*.php -print0 | \
xargs -0 sed -i 's%[^/"'\'']\+\.\(gif\|jpg\|jpeg\|png\)%images/\0%g' *.php
```

Caution, it will also change the path to images with remote urls. Also, make sure you have a full backup of your directory, php syntax and variable names might cause problems.